# Display PDF from external system to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, httprequest, apex-code

Following is the detail of the problem:-

1. Getting the list of records from another system(Using HTTP request in apex) and displaying them in our page.
2. We are also getting the bill(PDF) URL – [located in external system] along with each of the Invoice record.
   This URL is used to display a link in column.
3. On click of link we are opening a new visualforce page where we Pass PDF’s Url as a query parameter.
4. In new page, we are making another callout as per PDF URL and using the content of document, the PDF is displayed in new window.
5. This works fine in chrome but not in IE 8/9.

Error message:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8)
Timestamp: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 06:30:14 UTC

Message: The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally convinced client somehow to not use IE :)

Comment: A step in the right direction. One down  7,317,460,901 to go!